# Git commit a commit message and nothing else?

Tags: git, github, commit

When handling pull requests on GitHub, often I want to merge in commits from a branch with no changes. However, I would like to commit something just after the merge. I don't want to `git commit --amend` because that would change the commit I'm bringing in, so tracking the change gets more complicated.

Is there a way to `git commit` nothing but a message? The reason is because I might want to mention something in the Pull Request -- a URL pointing to a test case, or mention some other pull request so I can use a commit hook like `Closes #123` in addition to the original pull request.

Comment: Would something like a [note](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) serve your need or do you want it to be a commit?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I like the `--allow-empty` but it might be an abuse; I bet this `git note` business is probably more correct. I'll need to try it. I wonder if it these notes would show up in the history of a GitHub Pull Request.

Comment: I think in this case femaref's answer is best since it would let you put the message you want into the merge commit directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To commit an empty commit, use `git commit --allow-empty`.

Comment: This works like a champ and seems easier than @Femaref's suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git merge --no-commit branch` to make the merge but not autocommit. You are now able to tweak the actual commit like if the merge failed, including changing the commit message.

Furthermore, you are able to enter a message by `git merge -m "message" branch`, which is added to the merge commit.

Comment: Add `--no-ff` to explicitly generate a merge commit even if it is a fast forward.